# After reboot: Model 3 B+ shows up as client in router interface, but not responding to pings and has no internet connectivity

Tags: pi-3b+

Very odd problem here. I have Model 3 B+ running Pi-hole and dnscrypt-proxy. Everything was working just fine until this evening when it lost power for an extended period of time. Since powering it back on again, the Pi has zero internet connectivity and is not responding to pings.

Also, the Pi is showing the wrong time.

`ifconfig` show the assigned IP address, and my router shows the Pi as a client at that address (I checked to ensure the MAC address in the router interface matched that of the Pi.) `route` looks normal too.

I'm running the latest version of my entire stack.

I'm completely befuddled by this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with the router. Try rebooting your router first, then the pi. If that doesn't work, give some of the outputs of ping, etc.

Also, the Rpi doesn't have a real time clock on it so if it doesn't get set from the network it can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems if the Pi's time is sufficiently different from the actual time, it breaks internet connectivity. Solution: manually set the time using `sudo date 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'`. Then, after ensuring you have the right regional settings in Settings -> Raspberry Pi Configuration, reboot. This will force the Pi to update to the absolute correct time from the internet.